# AngularJS + Sharepoint + Rest API

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

Pessoal atualmente estou tentando desenvolver um script dentro do sharepoint usando o Script Editor mas está caindo no erro do meu código, como se a conexão não estivesse correta, porém, no Dev Http do google a requisição rest funciona. Segue o código:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <b>Welcome to AngularJS world in SharePoint 2013!</b>
    <div ng-controller="MyController" class="ng-scope">
        <div ng-repeat="p in Products">
            <table style="background-color:#f07432">
                <tr><td align="center"><b>Product Name: {{p.ProductName}}</b> </td></tr>
                <tr><td align="center"><img ng-src={{p.ProductImage}} /> </td></tr>
                <tr><td align="center"><b> Rate: Rs. {{p.ProductRate}}.</b></td></tr>
            </table>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyController($scope) {
        $scope.loadREST = function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate,ProductImage",
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    var newData = [];
                    jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
                        var pImage = value.ProductImage;
                        prImage = pImage.substring(0, pImage.indexOf(','));
                        newData.push({ ProductName: value.ProductName, ProductRate: value.ProductRate, ProductImage: prImage });
                    });
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.Products = newData;
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        };
        $scope.loadREST();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está entrando na condição de erro, isto significa que houve algum problema na requisição HTTP feita via Ajax.

No código mostrado, a variável `_spPageContextInfo` não está definida, mas é utilizada:

```rest
url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate,ProductImage",
```

Certifique-se de que o URL efetivamente contém o endereço correto.

Eu recomendo que utlize ou Firebug no Firefox ou as Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor no Chrome.

Com o Chrome, fica bem fácil analisar todos os detalhes de uma requisição HTTP. Tecle `SHIFT+CTRL+I`, clique na aba "**Network**", recarregue sua página e observe os resultados - deverá aparecer a sua chamada HTTP feita via Ajax pelo jQuery. Então, clique com o botão da direita do mouse sobre a chamada HTTP que apareceu na lista, em seguida clique em "**Copy All as HAR**" - e depois cole o resultado aqui na pergunta, pois conterá todos os detalhes da chamada HTTP que está falhando.

Comment: J. Bruni não funcionou da forma como disse. Como ele entra direto na minha condição de erro (que é mostrada na tela sempre que recarrego) o problema está na conexão, pois ele não faz o que está dentro de success. Não sei ainda o que pode ser. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Estou executando direto pelo sharepoint dentro de um Script Editor no local onde ele tem que funcionar. A requisição já testei inclusive colocando o mesmo endereço que uso no Dev Http do Chrome onde funciona e tras os itens corretamente. O erro quando rodo no ie10 direto do sharepoint usando o console do próprio ie10 é: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Erro de Rede 0x2ee7, Não foi possível concluir a operação. Erro: 00002ee7.

Comment: Pesquisei o erro 0x2ee7 significa "The server name could not be resolved" - ou seja, ou o endereço na URL está mesmo errado, ou há algum problema de DNS.

Comment: Mas pq no Dev Http o mesmo endereço funciona? Fiz o que vc sugeriu de abrir o log do chrome mas apareceu muita coisa, não sei qual copio.

Comment: Não sei - vai ver ele remove os espaços em branco automaticamente - estou sugerindo isso porque acabei de ler isto aqui: http://www.pc-library.com/errors/error-code/12007-0x2EE7/

Comment: É mesmo um problema de conexão...

Comment: Espera aí... na verdade, há muitos outros fatores para uma requisição HTTP ser bem-sucedida - os *headers* (cabeçalhos), *cookies*, etc, podem ser tão importantes quanto o endereço (URL).

Comment: O problema é que eu sou novo usando isso e não sei se tem algo a mais errado no código. O header eu estou colocando o mesmo que uso no Dev Http.

Comment: Definitivamente esse erro não tem a ver com o código, mas com a requisição HTTP mesmo. Talvez você precise mexer no código para incluir um header, mudar o URL, incluir um cookie. O ideal seria ter um raio-X exato para comparar as duas requisições HTTP. No Linux, eu usaria o Wireshark - não faço a menor ideia de uma ferramenta semelhante de "network sniffing" para o Windows.

Comment: É vou procurar por algo assim então pra poder ver melhor e posto aqui assim que conseguir mais alguma pista.

Comment: Nada feito. Continuo preso no mesmo ponto, já me aconselharam a modificar para `$http.get` no lugar de `jQuery.ajax()` mas não sei bem como fazer e acho que por isso também não funcionou. Mais alguma ideia? Esgotei as minhas.

Comment: Sugestão 1: remova a linha `headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },`

Comment: Sugestão 2: inclua `alert(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate,ProductImage");` antes de `jQuery.ajax({` - certifique-se que o endereço está certo - copie e cole aqui para a gente o que aparece no alert.

Comment: Sugestão 3: usando o DevHttp, salve a requisição bem sucedida, em seguida vá embaixo, em "REPOSITORY" - "Export", selecione a requisição para salvar a mesma num arquivo *json* - e então disponibilize esse arquivo para nós (seja editando a pergunta e colando o conteúdo, ou usando um serviço como *pastebin* ou outro) - aí a gente pode ter mais pistas para ajudar.

Comment: Quando fui colocar o endereço completo observei que estava colocando como http e no dev estava como https. Aparentemente era isso pois ele entrou no meu success onde coloquei um alert para confirmar se havia entrado, porém outro erro surgiu. O alert funciona mas está com esse erro: SCRIPT438: O objeto não oferece suporte à propriedade ou método 'indexOf'.

Comment: Pois é... foi o que disse desde o começo: "Certifique-se de que o URL efetivamente contém o endereço correto." :-) Quanto ao erro no "indexOf", significa que a variável "pImage" não é *string*. Para forçar que seja *string*, exprimente mudar a linha anterior para `var pImage = "" + value.ProductImage;`

Comment: Troquei como você sugeriu e funcionou como deveria. Cara muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13089/discussion-between-douglas-and-j-bruni)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta mudar o:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('....
```

para:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('....
```

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/153484)

Comment: Na verdade o erro que ele vem encontrando é na montagem no endereço de consulta no SharePoint. Enfrentei problema semelhante e no SharePoint Online essa alteração me garantiu a conexão corretamente.